# Delete a node from a Binary Search Tree

Tags: c++, performance, tree

I was recently solving a question on LeetCode platform to delete a node from a Binary Search Tree, I wrote the given below iterative solution, I was wondering if it was a good practice to add a `return` statement within every `if else` block, that way the control would never reach the end of the function, however doing that did improve the time to pass all test cases. Any help appreciated !

```
/**
 * Definition for a binary tree node.
 * struct TreeNode {
 *     int val;
 *     TreeNode *left;
 *     TreeNode *right;
 *     TreeNode(int x) : val(x), left(NULL), right(NULL) {}
 * };
*/
class Solution {
public:
TreeNode* deleteNode(TreeNode* root, int key) {
    if(!root)
        return NULL;
    if(root->val==key && !root->left && !root->right)
        return NULL;

    TreeNode* root1=root;
    TreeNode* parent=root;

    while(root1 && root1->val!=key){
        parent=root1;
        if(key<root1->val)
            root1=root1->left;
        else
            root1=root1->right;
    }

    TreeNode* delNode=root1;

    if(!root1)
        return root;

    if(!root1->left && !root1->right){
        if(parent->left==root1)
            parent->left=NULL;
        else
            parent->right=NULL;
        return root;
    }

    else if(root1->right){
        parent=root1;
        root1=root1->right;
        while(root1->left){
            parent=root1;
            root1=root1->left;
        }
        delNode->val=root1->val;
        if(parent==delNode)
            parent->right=root1->right;
        else
            parent->left=root1->right;

        return root;
    }
    else{
        if(parent==delNode)
            root=root->left;
        else 
            if(parent->left==delNode)
            parent->left=delNode->left;
        else
            parent->right=delNode->left;

        return root;
    }
    return root;
}
};
```

Comment: As the code is now, the final `return root;` is unreachable. Either delete that line or the `return root` lines in the previous if-else block. Either way is fine and I'd be very surprised if it made any performance difference.

Comment: Also, are you deleting a single node from the tree and reconnecting the child nodes? Or are you deleting the node and all of its children? Either way, there needs to be at least one `delete` statement in your code to actually delete the data.

Comment: I am not deleting any nodes as such, I am just reconnecting the nodes. I understand this causes memory leak.